# Difference between 妖魔 and 妖怪

Tags: difference

as in the title what is the difference between 妖魔 and 妖怪? Also, are there any similar words which have similar meaning?

Comment: ask online: https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=%E5%A6%96%E6%80%AA%E5%92%8C%E5%A6%96%E9%AD%94%E6%9C%89%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E5%8C%BA%E5%88%AB%EF%BC%9F&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002

Comment: **妖怪**  sprite monster genie bugbear demon bogey evil spirit
synonyms:妖, 妖精, 妖魔, 邪魔, 妖物, 怪物, 精, 怪, 精灵
**妖魔**  demon evil spirit bogey succubus goblin ogre devil
synonyms: 妖, 妖怪, 妖精, 邪魔, 妖物, 怪物, 精, 怪, 精灵
 demonization 妖魔化；妖化 see samples at jukuu

Comment: Your answers my second question very well. The website you recommend is an effective alternative for the www.yellowbridge.com

Answer (score 2):

As I write this, someone already left feedbacks for your second question.

As for the difference between 妖魔 and 妖怪:

妖怪: like a monster, its appearance looks quite different from other normal creatures (at least from what's in our minds).

妖魔: like a demon, having witch kind of looking, who can use the magic power in combat.

In short, 妖魔 has more magic power than 妖怪. 妖怪 is more powerful physically than its magic power.

This is my understanding and impression and might not be that accurate. Just as a reference.

Comment: 怪是真实存在的，只是奇异，而魔是不存在的，只是一种影响人的心理的幻觉。